# How to find an unknown error in create-react-app build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am receiving the following error when trying to build my react app.  The error isnt exactly clear.  When I run npm start I have no issues with the app.  Npm test shows no errors or warnings.

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Expected an attribute.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-firebase-authentication@0.1.1 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-firebase-authentication@0.1.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above
```

Node and NPM are up to date.  I am able to build other apps I am working on.  Not sure where to begin with this error.

Comment: It is clearly saying your error is from `react-firebase-authentication@0.1.1` build script and that's where you should look at.

Comment: Try using sudo sometimes it helps me